# Total revenue during intervals

Tags: functions, derivatives, economics

The rate of flow of revenue is given by  $$R'(t)=100t + 10e^{-t}$$ where $t$ is measured in years. Find the total revenue during the interval $$1 \le x \le 10$$

How can I calculate this because  the revenue function is $$P(x) = R(x) - C(x)$$
and if I had the cost function, I would be able to determine the costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** No, the total revenue function is $R(t)$. Thus the total revenue during the interval $1\leq t\leq 10$ is

$$R(t)=\int_1^{10} 100t + 10e^{-t} \; dt$$

Comment: When replacing R(t) in this function, do we use the first derivative or not?

Comment: @Jack I´m not sure what do you mean. To calculate the revenue $R(t)$ in the interval $1\leq t\leq 10$ we integrate $R^{'}(t)$ (first derivative of the revenue, marginal revenue): $\int_1^{10} R^{'}(t) \, dt=\left[ 50t^2-10\cdot e^{-t} \right]_1^{10}=5000-10\cdot e^{-10}-50+10\cdot e^{-1}$